# MVC Silverlight passing user context

Tags: silverlight, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, domainservices

I've got a MVC / Silverlight app and now need to begin passing data back and forward between the two. I've created a domainservice in my MVC project, but my question is regarding user context and authentication. What is the best way to handle this? In non MVC Silverlight projects I used to pass user ids etc in params.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found this site and used this method:
http://www.global-webnet.net/blogengine/post/2009/11/17/ASPNET-MVC-2-Passing-Parameters-to-Silverlight-application.aspx

Hope this helps someone else.